# How to quickly see parent tasks in MS Project

Tags: ms-project-2013

When working with a large plan spread over several screenfuls, it is difficult to see the place occupied by a given task in the task hierarchy. Is there any quick way to see the "outline path" that saves having to scroll up looking for the corresponding summary tasks? I like how MS Project automatically retains and displays the summary tasks when filtering by the task name. I guess if there was a "filter by current task" option, that would work for my need (however stupid it sounds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the **Summary Name** macro from Jack Dahlgren (www.masamiki.com/project/macros.htm).  It copies the Summary task name into Text12.  You can then add Text12 to a task view for quick reference.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looking at the macros suggested a simple approach to me. There is a macro called Filter_select that allows filtering by a selected task (which is the kind of solution I was hoping for, as per my question). This gave a simple idea: I can just add an ID column, then filter by the id of the task I want to look at. Works nicely.